# How do I pull the last level of a category?

Tags: templating

This allows me to pull the related categories from a second category group for a given category.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category).find() %}
{% set tags = craft.tags.relatedTo(entries).find() %}   
{% set markets = craft.categories.group('markets').relatedTo(entries).find() %}
```

**BUT**, it pulls both the parent and descendant categories from markets.  And, some markets do not have descendants - so adding `.level(2) would not capture those that only have a level(1) assigned.

**I want to list only the last level assigned whether it is level(1) or level(2).**

I tried adding `.last()` but that generates a `CException` error.

```
{% set markets = craft.categories.group('markets').last().relatedTo(entries).find() %}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: All entries have a category from markets assigned.  It is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

`.last` is the opposite of `.first`, meaning that you can only apply it at the *end* of your query.

```
{% set markets = craft.categories.group('markets').relatedTo(entries).last() %}
```

And similar to `.first`, the `.last` method will only return a single Entry.

Comment: That created a template error. `Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable ("8")`  So, is there a way to do it without using last()?  The goal is to pull all the markets using their last level to create filter buttons.

Comment: So, I am not trying to return a single entry or any entries.  See above.